# How to upload multipl file fiedls in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have form with 4 file fields and I want to upload these files properly.

My code is as follows :

```php
public function do_upload(){
    $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size']             = 100;
    $config['max_width']            = 1024;
    $config['max_height']           = 768;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
    } else {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

        $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I wrote an answer to a similar question the other day; Maybe this will help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62373664/adding-timestamp-while-uploading-image-file-is-not-working/62374346#62374346

Comment: What's your question about this? Can you explain what **exactly** is not working with the given code, and what you've tried to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
private function fileUpload($name, $config = []){
     $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
     $config['encrypt_name']         = TRUE;
     $config['file_ext_tolower']     = TRUE;
     $config['allowed_types']        = 'jpg|jpeg|png';
     $this->upload->initialize($config);
     if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($name))
     {
         $error = array('error' => true, 'message' => $this->upload->display_errors());
         return $error;
     }
     else
     {
         return array('error' => false, 'upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
     }
}
```

Create this private function in the controller just call this function when you have to upload the file with the name of the file field if you want some other config just pass config array to as a next parameter

```php
$data = $this->fileUpload('site_logo_dark')
if($data['error']){
  echo data['message']; // error message while uplaoding an file if have any
}else{
  echo $data['upload_data']['file_name']; // return you a name of the file which you just upload it you can save it to the database 
}
```