# image slider is not working properly for no_image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image, slider

I have image slider showing images which user uploaded. Every user has to uploaded at least 1 image and upto 4 as his interest. Uploading image 1 is compulsory. Rest which user didn't upload save as no_image.jpg file.

If someone upload 1 image, it repeats image1 2 times. it works fine and the way it's showing is ok. Problem is if someone upload 2 or 3 image, it repeats some images 2 times. It's bit odd.

I don't know much about coding. Please someone help me to solve this issue and work this perfectly. Your help is highly appreciated.

Edited:
image1 code is not displaying in here properly. I don't know issue. it is just shows image1. No if loop there.

```
<div class="product" >
<div class="thumbnail"><img src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>assets/images/adsimages/<?php
                                        $a = 'no_image.jpg';
                                        $b = $post['image2'];
                                        $c = $post['image3'];
                                        $d = $post['image4'];

                                        if ($b != $a) {
                                            echo $post['image2'];
                                        } elseif ($c != $a){
                                            echo $post['image3'];
                                        }elseif ($d != $a){
                                            echo $post['image4'];
                                        }else echo $post['image1']
                                        ?>" ></div>
</div>
<div class="product" >
<div class="thumbnail"><img src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>assets/images/adsimages/<?php
                                        $a = 'no_image.jpg';

                                        $c = $post['image3'];
                                        $d = $post['image4'];

                                        if ($c != $a){
                                            echo $post['image3'];
                                        }elseif ($d != $a){
                                            echo $post['image4'];
                                        }else echo $post['image1']
                                        ?>" ></div>
 </div>
 <div class="product" >
 <div class="thumbnail"><img src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>assets/images/adsimages/<?php
                                        $a = 'no_image.jpg';
                                        $d = $post['image4'];
                                            if ($d != $a){
                                            echo $post['image4'];
                                        }else echo $post['image1']
                                        ?>"></div>
                                </div>
```

Comment: Please show what is the value inside `$post`

Comment: $post array contains all 4 images(image1,image2, image3, image4).  image1 contains different images since user has to be upload image1 since it is compulsory. Other 3 images may not have uploaded images because it is optional. Rest is save as no_image.jpg image file. ex: if someone upload first 2 images. They are saved as no_image.jpg file.   What I want in here is slider shows only uploaded images.skip no_image.jpg image.  I think  you got your answer. if you need anything let me know. thanks @sauhardnc  for your help.

Comment: so, if the user uploads 2 images, you'd want only 3 images in the slider, right? 2 the user uploaded and  1 no_image.jpg and ignore duplicate no_image.jpg, right?

Comment: No. I want to show only that 2 images which are user uploaded in that slider. I don't want to show  no_image.jpg.

Comment: ok, so if you use my code then it shows 3 images in this case, right?

Comment: Actually It's not working properly. I tried several times. Can you give another method if you can.

Comment: I think it should show at least 3 images in this case. Can you do a quick `print_r($post);` and show the result?

Comment: your code isn't give any error. but it's not show images.   Array ( [id] => 417 [image1] => 1592386750about_img4.jpg [image2] => no_image.jpg [image3] => 1592386554p8.jpg [image4] => no_image.jpg

Comment: I've updated the answer, see if it fixes your issue.

Comment: It didn't work. But I tried this one.

Comment: <?php
                                    $a = 'no_image.jpg';
                                    $b= $post['image2'];
                                    if ($a!=$b){
                                        ?>
                                        <div class="product" >
                                            <div class="thumbnail"><img src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>assets/images/adsimages/<?php echo $post['image2']?>" style="width: 550px"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php }
                                    ?>

Comment: Likewise check other image3 and image4. It may not the professional way. But it works fine.

Comment: Ok, whatever works for you. :)

Comment: Thanks for your support. Highly appreciated. :)

Comment: HI   I have another problem. If you have time please help me. Thanks in advance.     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62688415/image-slider-modification

Answer (score 0):

You can use `foreach` to show the date and prevent yourself from repeating the code. For your problem, you can take an empty `array` and fill it on every `iteration` and check if there is a duplicate value, if not then show the image, if yes, then don't.

I've written a possible solution for your code, comments are mentioned in the code itself. See if it helps you.

```
<?php 
    $imageArr = array(); // make an empty array

    foreach($post as $key => $singleImage){ // loop all the images 

        // if( !in_array($singleImage, $imageArr) ){ // check if current value already exists in array ie no_image 
        if( $key != 'id' && $singleImage != 'no_image.jpg' ) ){ // check if key is not id and its value is not no_image.jpg

            // $imageArr[] = $singleImage; // push the current value in array
?>
            <!-- Your view code here -->
            <div class="product" >
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>assets/images/adsimages/$singleImage; ?>" /> 
                </div>
            </div>
<?php 
        }
    } 
?>
```