# Image Slider modification

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, jquery-mobile, slider

I am using this image slider in my website which mentioned link down below
It is only working when pressing the next and previous button. what I need is, I need to work that slider with that button and moving finger(for mobile phones).
Your help is highly appreciated.

https://codepen.io/andytran/pen/xweoPN/

Comment: You can use plugins or library for that - https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin, https://github.com/dimsemenov/photoswipe, https://codepen.io/dimsemenov/pen/ZYbPJM, https://www.ajax-zoom.com/examples/example31.php

Comment: Thanks for your help. One more thing. Not related to this question above. I am using hostgator server. In my database table, there is a table column "created_at" which set CURRENT TIME STAMP. When I enter data it saves server time America. I need to edit time zone to ASIA. So I changed the php.ini file as well to ASIA. When check phpinfo.php, it shows timezone ASIA. But I enter data it saves as american timezone.

Comment: This might be because when you use `current timestamp` it saves the date according to `MySQL` configuration not `PHP`. Now you can either provide date by giving the variable value in `PHP` itself(not dependent on `MySQL`) or by changing the database configuration. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34428563/set-timezone-in-php-and-mysql and https://phoenixnap.com/kb/change-mysql-time-zone#:~:text=Option%202%3A%20Edit%20the%20MySQL%20Configuration%20File,-MySQL%20settings%20can&text=Scroll%20down%20to%20the%20%5Bmysqld,Save%20the%20file%20and%20exit.